# Which XPathAPI should I use in Java 1.5?

Tags: java, xpath, xpath-api

I have been using com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.XPathAPI for some time and it seems to work ok. Recently I tried to use the TPTP profiler in Eclipse but it could not find the XPathAPI class.

I haven't figured this problem yet but it did make me wonder whether I should be using a class in an 'internal' package? Should I be using the Xalan library? Or what??

(I'm currently using JRE 1.5.0_06 for this project)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All classes under the com.sun package are internal implementation details. You should never reference them directly.

The base for xPath in the JDK is [javax.xml.xpath](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/package-frame.html).

Answer (score 1):

Use the `XPathFactory.newInstance()` method in the `javax.xml.path` package.

I think this was introduced in Java 1.5. If you have to revert to Java 1.4 or earlier, I think you have to use the `com.sun` packages, which is never really a good idea (but sometimes unavoidable)

Comment: Don't really see how that helps. XPathFactory.newInstance() does not get you a XPathAPI...

Comment: XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath() gives you an XPath.

Comment: Yes, but my question was about whether or not to use the XPathAPI class. It doesn't answer the question at all IMHO

Comment: "... use the com.sun packages, which is never really a good idea". So if you're on Java 1.5, then you should be using the javax.xml.xpath package and its component classes (one of which is XPathFactory)

Answer (score 1):

If performance is any sort of issue, whatever you do, don't use Xalan for this. The Xalan XPathAPI interface is very slow. We wrap Jaxen to provide an XPathAPI-like interface. That is vastly quicker.

Answer (score 1):

I dropped in the Xalan jar (2.7.0) and used org.apache.xpath.XPathAPI in the import
and the deprecation messages went away.

Comment: This is the correct answer and I recently had the same problem. I had a Xalan.jar in the lib directory but it wasn't included in the Java Build Path of the project.

Answer (score 0):

We use jdom but apache commons is always a good choice for everything.